# Firestore query to retrieve users based on last connection and presence of field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection called `users` that contains user documents. Each user document has an optional field called `previewPosts`, which is an array representing the user's four most recent posts. Additionally, there is another field called `lastConnection` that stores the timestamp of the user's last online connection.

I want to implement a query on the `users` collection that retrieves the top 10 users based on their last connection and ensures that they have the optional `previewPosts` field defined **with at least one post in the array**.

How can I construct a Firestore query to achieve this?

I have tried the following:

```js
const query = firestore
  .collection("users")
  .orderBy("lastConnection", "desc")
  .orderBy("previewPosts");
```

Is creating an extra field the best approach?

```js
  const query = firestore
    .collection("users")
    .where("hasPreviewPhotos", "==", true)
    .orderBy("lastConnection", "desc");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, creating an extra field is likely the best way.  You could make it be a count rather than a boolean if you wanted to order by how many previews rather than just the existence, and this would later allow you to filter based on the number too (say "only users with more than 2 previews").

Comment: but could be impossible to sort by last connection date first if I do `.where("totalPreviewPosts", ">", N)` right? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations

Comment: If the result set isn't huge (10 results), then you could simply sort them on the client, right?